# WP ACF Field on User (Image) disappears from time to time

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multisite

I have an ACF Field called `avatar` on `User Form` (is this wrong?) which would work correctly, I can set the avatar image for each users. This field however is being nulled (disappears) from time to time, I have read countless topics trying to find somebody with similar problem but I had no luck.

This is a WP Multisite. The images I uploaded for the users are already thumbnail sizes (150x150), since WP would make this Thumbnail sizes itself (image preview size is set to thumbnail too), could it lead to some errors and that to disappearing images? Doesn't make much sense because then they'd be supposed to disappear as soon as I add them. It doesn't happen to all of the users in the same time.

If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Comment: are you sure that you not overwrite it in some part of your code? maybe calling `update_field('avatar', $avatar, $user_id);` in a context in which $avatar is null?

Comment: We need to see your code to understand what's going on so please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can test it out and help you debug it.

Comment: sorry guys I didn't get any emails from your replies and I have just seen them, I found the source of the problem, I am using the same authors in multisite and when I update the user in one site the other one will be overwritten from that too. Pretty annoying but I'll be able to solve this with ACF Fields probably. Anway thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to WP Multisite. Whenever we changed a user's avatar on one of the sites in the other sites it was removed. We thought that these datas are handled separately, but unfortunately not. So we decided to create `user meta fields` instead and it seems to work just as we need it to work.
I add the code that worked for me (took a bit long to make it work and I copied most of them from different sources), maybe it helps somebody. (the hard part was the image)

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'media_selector_settings_page_callback');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'media_selector_settings_page_callback');
function media_selector_settings_page_callback($user)
{
    // Save attachment ID
    if (isset($_POST['submit_image_selector']) && isset($_POST['avatar-en'])) :
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'avatar-en', absint($_POST['avatar-en']));
    endif;
    wp_enqueue_media();
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="bio-en"><?php _e("Bio-en"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <textarea name="bio-en" id="bio-en" class="regular-text" rows="8"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('bio-en', $user->ID)); ?></textarea>
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your bio-en."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="avatar"><?php _e("Avatar-en"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <div class='image-preview-wrapper'>
                    <img id='image-preview-en' src='<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('avatar-en', $user->ID))); ?>' height='100'>
                </div>
                <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e('Upload image'); ?>" />
                <input type='hidden' name='avatar-en' id='avatar-en' value='<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('avatar-en', $user->ID)); ?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="bio-de"><?php _e("Bio-de"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <textarea name="bio-de" id="bio-de" class="regular-text" rows="8"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('bio-de', $user->ID)); ?></textarea>
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your bio-de."); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="avatar"><?php _e("Avatar-de"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <div class='image-preview-wrapper'>
                    <img id='image-preview-de' src='<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('avatar-de', $user->ID))); ?>' height='100'>
                </div>
                <input id="upload_image_button-de" type="button" class="button" value="<?php _e('Upload image'); ?>" />
                <input type='hidden' name='avatar-de' id='avatar-de' value='<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('avatar-de', $user->ID)); ?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'media_selector_print_scripts');
function media_selector_print_scripts()
{
    $my_saved_attachment_post_id = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id', 0);
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Uploading files
            var file_frame;
            var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
            var set_to_post_id = <?php echo $my_saved_attachment_post_id; ?>; // Set this
            jQuery('#upload_image_button').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
                if (file_frame) {
                    // Set the post ID to what we want
                    file_frame.uploader.uploader.param('post_id', set_to_post_id);
                    // Open frame
                    file_frame.open();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
                }
                // Create the media frame.
                file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: 'Select a image to upload',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Use this image',
                    },
                    multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
                });
                // When an image is selected, run a callback.
                file_frame.on('select', function() {
                    // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
                    attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
                    $('#image-preview-en').attr('src', attachment.url).css('width', 'auto');
                    $('#avatar-en').val(attachment.id);
                    // Restore the main post ID
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
                });
                // Finally, open the modal
                file_frame.open();
            });
            // Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
            jQuery('a.add_media').on('click', function() {

                wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'media_selector_print_scripts_de');
function media_selector_print_scripts_de()
{
    $my_saved_attachment_post_id = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id', 0);
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Uploading files
            var file_frame;
            var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
            var set_to_post_id = <?php echo $my_saved_attachment_post_id; ?>; // Set this
            jQuery('#upload_image_button-de').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
                if (file_frame) {
                    // Set the post ID to what we want
                    file_frame.uploader.uploader.param('post_id', set_to_post_id);
                    // Open frame
                    file_frame.open();
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
                }
                // Create the media frame.
                file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: 'Select a image to upload',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Use this image',
                    },
                    multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
                });
                // When an image is selected, run a callback.
                file_frame.on('select', function() {
                    // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
                    attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
                    $('#image-preview-de').attr('src', attachment.url).css('width', 'auto');
                    $('#avatar-de').val(attachment.id);
                    // Restore the main post ID
                    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
                });
                // Finally, open the modal
                file_frame.open();
            });
            // Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
            jQuery('a.add_media').on('click', function() {

                wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}

add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');
function save_extra_user_profile_fields($user_id)
{
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'avatar-en', absint($_POST['avatar-en']));
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'avatar-de', absint($_POST['avatar-de']));
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'bio-en', $_POST['bio-en']);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'bio-de', $_POST['bio-de']);
}

$args = array(
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_meta('user', 'avatar-en', $args);
register_meta('user', 'avatar-de', $args);
register_meta('user', 'bio-en', $args);
register_meta('user', 'bio-de', $args);
```